# MSSQL to PostgreSQL synchronisation using sync orchestra

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, synchronization

I have worked on MSSQL<->MSSQL and MSSQL<->SqlCe  synchronization using Microsoft sync Framework. they work fine.
Is it possible to sync MSSQL database and PostgreSQL ?
if yes ,please help me to find some samples

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to sync MSSQL database and PostgreSQL ?

Yes.  There are no fundamental problems that are specific there, so if you can write software to sync MS SQL and SQL CE, then it should be possible to write software to sync MS SQL and PostgreSQL.

> if yes ,please help me to find some samples

You might take a look at how [rubyrep](http://www.rubyrep.org) does things.  These things are not easy though in the best of circumstances.